# Find the optimal solution without going through the ERO's

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, simplex, operations-research, constraints

[image]

---

All I got is that

$$12y_1 + 7y_2 + 10y_3 = 2(0) + 4(10.4) + 3(0) + 1(0.4)$$

and

$y_2 = 0$ because $x_6$ is in basis.

How do I find $y_1$ and $y_3$ without going through the simplex method?

I took the dual and that doesn't seem to help.

I know that $y_1 = z_5 - c_5$ and $y_3 = z_7 - c_7$, but how do I find $z_i - c_i$?

---

From Chapter 2 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the dual:

$$\min z' = 12y_1 +7y_2 + 10y_3$$

s.t.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & 2\\ 
1 & 3 & 1\\ 
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
4 & 3 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ 
y_2\\ 
y_3
\end{bmatrix} \ge \begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
4\\ 
3\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since the dual of the dual is the primal, the dual of the dual variables are the primal variables.

Using complementary slackness on the dual, we have:

$$x_1 \mathcal{S}_1 = 0$$

$$x_2 \mathcal{S}_2 = 0$$

$$x_3 \mathcal{S}_3 = 0$$

$$x_4 \mathcal{S}_4 = 0$$

$$\because x_2, x_4 > 0, \mathcal{S}_2 = \mathcal{S}_4 = 0$$

Thus,

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1\\ 
4 & 3 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ 
y_2\\ 
y_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\to \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 1\\ 
4 & 3 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ 
0\\ 
y_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\to \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
4 & -1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ 
y_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\to y_1 = 1, y_3 = 3$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: With these values of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, it is clear that the basic variables are $x_2,x_4$ and $x_6$ (the slack variable for the second constraint).

Therefore, it is easy to find the optimal tableau, from which you can directly read the values of the dual variables (do you see where?).

Comment: Because the second constraint is not tight, which means the slack variable is positive, therefore in the basis.

Comment: If you replace $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ by their values, you get either an inequality, or an equality. If it is an equality, than the constraint is tight.

Comment: Thanks @Kuifje. So $y_2=0$ but what about $y_1$ and $y_3$?

Comment: $-y_1$ and $-y_3$ equal the reduced cost of slack variables $x_5$ and $x_7$, respectively.

Comment: 2 and 3 you mean?

Comment: No, $y_1$ is the dual variable associated with constraint $1$, with slack variable $x_5$, and $y_3$ is dual variable associated with with constraint $3$, with slack variable $x_7$.

Comment: Oh right zj-cj. I remember now. So how do I get those?

Comment: In the optimal tableau…that you need to compute knowing that variables $x_2$, $x_4$ and $x_6$ are the basic optimal variables.

Comment: Kuifje, I thought the whole point of the problem is not using the simplex method. I could easily answer this with a computer which would give me the $z_j - c_j$'s.

Comment: I never said you should use the simplex method :) once you know the basic variables, you only have to inverse the initial matrix to get the optimal tableau.

Comment: Oh wait I think I remember. Is this something like coefficients of the x's multiplied to the inverse of the original matrix?

Comment: Kuifje, should we use complementary slackness like what was done [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181171/)? I posted an answer

Comment: You said inverse. did you mean transpose?